# Add class to date datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to add classes to dates in the datepicker.

I tried to add array of classes but it doesnt work.

```
var dates = ['07/13/2019', '07/18/2019']; //
//tips are optional but good to have
var tips = ['some description', 'some other description'];
var classes = ['class1', 'class2'];

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
 showOtherMonths: true,
 numberOfMonths: 1,
});

function highlightDays(date) {
 for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
   if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
     return [true, 'highlight', tips[i], classes[i]];
   }
 }
 return [true, ''];
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/834cf6rv/3/

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, can you show us your current HTML and an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing *wrong* with your code. jQuery UI DatePicker only reads 3 elements:

> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
>
> `[0]`: `true`/`false` indicating whether or not this date is selectable
>
> `[1]`: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or `""` for the default presentation
>
> `[2]`: an optional popup tooltip for this date

So you cannot add classes in the 4th index. You can append them to your classes string in index 1. Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var dates = ['07/13/2019', '07/18/2019'];
  var tips = ['some description', 'some other description'];
  var classes = ['class1', 'class2'];

  function compareDates(a, b) {
    if (typeof a === "string") {
      a = new Date(a);
    }
    if (typeof b === "string") {
      b = new Date(b);
    }
    return a.toString() === b.toString();
  }

  function highlightDays(date) {
    var result = [true, '', ''];
    $.each(dates, function(i, d) {
      if (compareDates(d, date)) {
        result = [true, 'highlight ' + classes[i], tips[i]];
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Some minor changes, one using `$.each()`, I just prefer it to `for()`. I also added a more robust function to compare a date to another date.

Hope that helps.